# Tile Image not shown

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, live-tile

I try to set my main tile with the templatew TileWide310x150SmallImageAndText02. I had a look at the sample code and took this out of it:

```
            ITileSquare310x310SmallImagesAndTextList04 tileContent =
            TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare310x310SmallImagesAndTextList04();
        tileContent.Image1.Src = "ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png";
        tileContent.TextHeading1.Text = "Cashflow";
        tileContent.TextWrap1.Text = "Income: 500";
        tileContent.TextWrap2.Text = "Spending: 400";
        tileContent.TextWrap3.Text = "Earnings: 200";

        // Create a notification for the Wide310x150 tile using one of the available templates for the size.
        ITileWide310x150SmallImageAndText02 wide310x150Content =
            TileContentFactory.CreateTileWide310x150SmallImageAndText02();
        wide310x150Content.Image.Src = "ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png";
        wide310x150Content.TextHeading.Text = "Cashflow";
        wide310x150Content.TextBody1.Text = "Income: 500";
        wide310x150Content.TextBody2.Text = "Spending: 400";
        wide310x150Content.TextBody3.Text = "Earnings: 200";

        // Create a notification for the Square150x150 tile using one of the available templates for the size.
        ITileSquare150x150PeekImageAndText01 square150x150Content =
            TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare150x150PeekImageAndText01();
        square150x150Content.Image.Src = "ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png";
        square150x150Content.TextHeading.Text = "Cashflow";
        square150x150Content.TextBody1.Text = "Income: 500";
        square150x150Content.TextBody2.Text = "Spending: 300";
        square150x150Content.TextBody3.Text = "Earnings: 200";

        // Attach the Square150x150 template to the Wide310x150 template.
        wide310x150Content.Square150x150Content = square150x150Content;

        // Attach the Wide310x150 template to the Square310x310 template.
        tileContent.Wide310x150Content = wide310x150Content;

        // Send the notification to the application? tile.
            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileContent.CreateNotification());
```

This will show the tile correctly in the 150x150 size, but not in the wide. Then only the text is shown but not the image.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks for your help!
NPadrutt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SmallImageAndText Templates only show an Image on Windows, not on Phone.

Please refer to the [template catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#TileWideSmallImageAndText02) for the direfences here.

Tipp: Template catalog is available at [aka.ms/tiletemplates](http://aka.ms/tiletemplates)